# Android: Best way to get instant location once per use

Tags: android, location

I always had some difficulties to find a good way for the instant location of the device.
What I want to do is once per use of the app (e.g. when the onCreate of an activity is called) i want to know the coordinates of the device in that exact moment and never ask for them again. 
What I think could be the best way is to have something like a static Class with a function similar to :

```
coordinates getCoordinates();
```

Some advice/snippet to give?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found what I really was searching in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3145655/1830034) answer.

I have only added two controls; i check if:

- gps_loc.getTime() (or net_loc.getTime()) is bigger than System.currentTimeMillis() - 300000 (5 minutes ago). In the method run() of the inner class GetLastLocation;
- location.getAccuracy() < 100. In the method onLocationChanged() of both LocationListeners (network and GPS).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 6):

Use `LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation` or `LocationManager.requestSingleUpdate`.

The first will return immediately, but may return *null* if no location is already available.

The second will return your data on a callback, but will wake up whatever provider is needed and will get a good location (if possible).

Comment: I have found what I really was searching in [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3145655/1830034)answer